# Manipulation gesture with effect like FlipView

Tags: windows-runtime, gesture, flipview

I have a page with content detail.
Currently now is just for single page but my friend want the detail page can be scrolled left and right like flipview control.
I am currently have some difficulties to change the View Model to become FlipView. So I want to using gesture in my content detail page. 
How I can achieve flipview animation using the gesture manipulation?
What I mean with flipview animation is when scrolled left or right, I can see the previous or next item.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the controls before or behind your visible item by setting their `TranslateX` of `TraslateTransform` and use the `Clip` proprety of the visible item.

I have build a FlipView-like control that acts like a `FlipView` but it can loops. Here is the xaml code:

```
<Style TargetType="local:LoopingBannerControl">  
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LoopingBannerControl">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFF0F0F0" d:DesignWidth="199.667" d:DesignHeight="215.222">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="NextStory">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="NextImageBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="NextRightOriTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0" Value="200"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentImageBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="NextMiddleOriTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="NextMiddleTargetTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="-200"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="PreviousStory">
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentImageBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="PreviousMiddleOriTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="PreviousMiddleTargetTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="200"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousImageBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame x:Name="PreviousLeftOriTranslateXFrame" KeyTime="0" Value="-200"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="ShowBtnStory">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousBtn">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NextBtn">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.5"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="NextBtn">
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.5"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="HideBtnStory">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousBtn">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="NextBtn">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousBtn">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="NextBtn">
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.5"/>
                                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0 0 200 200"/>
                        </Grid.Clip>
                        <Button x:Name="PreviousImageBtn" Background="{x:Null}" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-200"/>
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                            <Image x:Name="PreviousImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="NextImageBtn" Background="{x:Null}" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="200"/>
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                            <Image x:Name="NextImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="CurrentImageBtn" Background="{x:Null}" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Button.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform/>
                            </Button.RenderTransform>
                            <Image x:Name="CurrentImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </Button>

                        <Button x:Name="PreviousBtn" Background="#FFEAEAEA" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="25" Opacity="0" Padding="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="&lt;"/>
                        </Button>
                        <Button x:Name="NextBtn" Background="#FFEAEAEA" BorderThickness="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="25" Padding="0" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="&gt;"/>
                        </Button>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="IndexIndicatorSP" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The `Storyboard` part is the animation of switching item. You should paste it to your project to see what happens :-)

Comment: how to use it? just use the style in root page or how?

Comment: Nope, it's a style of a Custom control. I am considering posting it to GitHub.

Comment: maybe wanna share it? Hopefully I can use this :D